# Identify the word

Tags: riddle, word

I am a word.

When by none, I am erroneous.
When by one, extraneous.
When surrounded by any, I am the one.
Yet when I am to any by many, said any approaches none.

What am I?

Comment: Nice riddle! +1 to question and answer.

Comment: totally awesome riddle :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like

> division.

When by none, I am erroneous.

> Division by zero results in an error.

When by one, extraneous.

> Division by one returns the original number.

When surrounded by any, I am the one.

> Any nonzero N divided by any nonzero N equals one. The division sign is "surrounded" by N.

Yet when I am to any by many, said any approaches none.

> $ \lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{N}{x}=0$